# How to exchange partition within same hive table

Tags: hive

I need help in exchanging the partition within the same table.Let us assume that I have one table with the below definition.

create table test (ID STRING) partitioned by (data_processed string,date1 string);

id      data_processed  date1

1       0               2018-07-17

1       1               2018-07-16

Now , I want to move the data for partiton(2018-07-17) under data_processed partition '1'.

Desired result:

id      data_processed  date1

1       1               2018-07-17

1       1               2018-07-16

How to achieve this. Does hive exchange partition supports multi level exchange partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hive rename partition command.

Here you can run -->

```
alter table test partition (data_processed='0',date1='2018-07-17') 
            rename to partition(data_processed='1',date1='2018-07-17');
```